# How do I paint text with 2 colors in CSS?

Tags: css

[image]

i did it with photoshop but how can i do it with css? I want to paint the hat of the letter g?

Comment: I think you should use css `pseudo` elements to do this. Maybe `:before` or `:after`

Answer (score 0):

Decompose the character, colour the 'COMBINING BREVE' (U+0306) separately:

```css
* {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<span style="color:black">g</span><span style="color:red">&#774;</span>
```

EDIT: Apparently only works on my browser :P

Comment: This sure *seems* like it should work, but at least on Chrome current and FF 56, both appear to have the same color, perhaps because they're interpreted together or something. Giving one element a different style (like a border) results in a different color as desired, but then the characters get horizontally separated

Comment: @CertainPerformance Hm... too bad. I only tested on Chrome/Mac 76, and it worked. It fails (decomposes) on Safari/Mac 12.1.1, and fails (both black) on Firefox/Mac 69. Oh well, was worth a try... I guess you can do something similar with overlaying with non-combining breve... it's more work though.

Comment: unfortunately it's one color :(